# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

Received following error for my Capybara test in terminal:

```
Failures:

  1) Users User create new user
     Failure/Error: fill_in 'Username', with: 'Ali', visible: false

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Username" that is not disabled within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="form" path="/html/body/form">
     # ./spec/features/users_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/features/users_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>
```

My test code in capybara:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.feature "Users", type: :feature do
  describe "User", :type => :feature do
    it "create new user" do
      visit '/signup'
      within('form') do
        fill_in 'Username', with: 'Ali', visible: false
        fill_in 'Password', with: 'ali', visible: false
      end
      click_button 'Submit'
      expect(page).to have_content 'User successfully created.'
    end
  end
end
```

My view file

```
<h1>Create New User</h1>
<%= form_for :user, url: '/users' do |f| %>
  Username: <%= f.text_field :username %>
  Password: <%= f.password_field :password %>
  Uplaod your photo: <%= f.file_field :image %>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

And my controller:

```
  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      redirect_to '/users/index', notice: 'User successfully created.'
    else
      redirect_to '/signup'
    end
  end
```

I did some research, this was due to the issue on capybara 2x, and most peoples solved by adding visible: false, but this solution couldn't works on me.

Appreciate for the help from the pro out there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't fill in fields that are non-visible, so passing `visible: false` to `fill_in` makes no sense.

The reason `fill_in` isn't finding your fields is because it finds fields by id, name, or associated label text.  You don't show the actual HTML of your page but the fact that 'Username' and 'Password' aren't actually in label elements would mean that you can't find by associated label text so that won't work.  You could put the text into `<label>` elements and associate with the respective fields (`for` attribute or wrapping), or you could select the fields to fill_in by id or name.  Without the actual HTML it's impossible to say for sure, but something like

```
fill_in 'user_username', with: 'Ali'
fill_in 'user_password', with: 'ali'
```

will probably work, matching on the fields ids,

or

```
fill_in 'user[username]', with: 'Ali'
fill_in 'user[password]', with: 'ali'
```

matching on the fields name attributes.

Comment: Hey thanks man, it works! Thanks for your hep in saving my code. Appreciate it a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the same problem with that way:
in some of my js code were `` instead of ''. Browser can understand that syntax (it `` needs for interpolation), but Capybara couldn't.

When I've changed `` to '', the problem is gone.