# Unable to find visible field nil that is not disabled

Tags: angularjs, selenium, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here as I'm totally new to capybara. I can find an element with

```
all('.mold_table_input').last
#<Capybara::Node::Element tag="input" path="/html/body/md-content/section/md-content/md-tabs/md-tabs-content-wrapper/md-tab-content/div/div/div/md-card/md-card-content/div/form/md-content/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input">
```

but when I try `all('.mold_table_input').last.fill_in(with: '02')` I get the following error

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible field nil that is not disabled within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="input" path="/html/body/md-content/section/md-content/md-tabs/md-tabs-content-wrapper/md-tab-content/div/div/div/md-card/md-card-content/div/form/md-content/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[12]/input">
```

I'm using angularjs on my front end. Also when I check the visibility like `all('.mold_table_input').last.visible?` it returns `true`

Comment: did you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938918/capybaraelementnotfound-unable-to-find-visible-field

Answer (score 1):

What version of Capybara are you using?  I’m guessing  < 3.7 since that’s where the ability to call `fill_in` on the element to be modified was added. Prior to 3.7 it would only attempt to find a valid descendant to work on. Even in 3.7+ using `fill_in` like you are attempting to isn’t recommended when you have a simple unique locator since it adds overhead for no reason. In this case you’re dealing with a unique element locator (element id should be unique on a HTML page) so you have no need to be using ‘all(...).last` and should just do

```
  fill_in ‘mold_table_input’, with: ‘02’
```

On a related note, if you do ever need to locate an element for more complicated interaction you really should prefer `find` over `all` when you have elements that can be located uniquely. Not only will `find` be faster, but `all` has a few subtle limitations on dynamic pages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the detail just posting to help others the following line did the trick

```
find('.mold_table_input', match: :first).set('06')
```

I was able to set the value of input field by finding first and use of set rather than `fill_in`

Comment: There’s no need to do find.set - just use fill_in - `fill_in('mold_table_input', with: ‘06’, match: :first)` if you really need the :first matching (you shouldn’t since ids are required to be unique - so needing :first would imply you have invalid HTML)